# How do I update my visual studio project without publishing it again?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a program and I made some patches in it and now I want to update it to my USB without having to delete the old one and publish the new one since I am making a self-contained application and it takes time for it to get published.

Comment: If they're minor changes only, no new libraries etc you can probably just copy the exe out of the bin/release folder in your project, and overwrite the installed exe with it. If it works you can set up a copy script that you call in the Post Build event, and you can even have that script contain an "if build configuration equals blahblah do the copy" so you can choose whether to copy or not by making another build config(the dropdown arrow next to Debug/Release at the top of vs window)

Comment: can you rewrite this question but this time write it as if you are writing it to a person that does not know visual studio mechanics at all :D

Comment: Double click on Program.cs in the solution explorer to open it. Right click on the tab for Program.cs and choose Open Containing Folder. Windows explorer opens. Open the bin folder. Open the release folder (or whatever name you have there for your production build). Open the eg net5 folder (or whatever name you have there, maybe none). There is your built exe. Copy it and paste it over the top of your exe in its install location and see if it runs with the new changes. If it does you can make a dos batch script  you can double click on to perform the copy, to make your life a bit easier

Comment: much more understandable. thank you Caius Jard